# FakeItEasy does not allow to setup value to return

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I cannot understand why `FakeItEasy` does not allow me to set return value for public method with parameters.

The code:

```
var fakeInstanse = A.Fake<SomeClass>();
A.CallTo(() => fakeInstanse.Method(param1, param1));
```

The `Method` is the public one, accepts two parameters. Normally I would call `Returns()` method on second line of code, but Visual Studio does not show it among available.

What might affect this behavior? What part of `SomeClass` or `Method` definition might cause this?

Answer (score 3):

In general, this should work. Check out this passing test:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public virtual int Method(int arg1, int arg2)
    {
        return 7;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_be_able_to_set_return_value()
    {
        const int param1 = 9;
        var fakeInstanse = A.Fake<SomeClass>();
        A.CallTo(() => fakeInstanse.Method(param1, param1))
            .Returns(8);
        Assert.That(fakeInstanse.Method(param1, param1), Is.EqualTo(8));
    }
}
```

What's the return type of your `Method`? From your description, I'd guess that it's `void`.

Could you show us the declaration of SomeClass (and SomeClass.Method)? Otherwise, we're not going to be able to give constructive answers. Also, you may find some help at [the FakeItEasy "what can be faked" documentation page](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/What-can-be-faked).

Comment: I know this is old, but figured it's worth sharing. Make sure the object you are trying to return matches your method's return type. Sounds obvious, but when refactoring code (like I was) this had me confused for a good 15m. The compiler error wasn't too helpful even though it was clearly saying what the problem was in too many words.